# Why tabs don't worknig on uiv VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

guys, I have a problem with VueJS and bootstrap.

Here is my component uiv and vueJS 2. In the browser I get error: `[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: Tab parent must be Tabs."`

What I am doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <tabs>
        <tab>Test</tab>
    </tabs>
</template>

<script>
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'uiv'

export default {
  name: 'headerpanel',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  components: {
      'tabs': Tabs,
      'tab': Tab
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've generated a simple project with vue-cli `vue init webpack my-project`
https://github.com/bsalex/vue-tabs-simplest

and used your code here https://github.com/bsalex/vue-tabs-simplest/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

and I see no errors. Are you sure that you have the error in this file?